# By cross-pollination of two gloxins we will get new hybrids?

Tags: houseplants

What colors will the hybrids result from these two combinations?[image]

Comment: No idea - with paints, you'd get a sludgy magenta/brown colour,but with plants, depends which genes are dominant in the colour mixes.

Comment: Usually for hybrids we intend crossing two different species. With the same species you will just have a mixed DNA. The colour is unknown: we do not know the initial DNA: e.g. one is really a pure red variety, or a multicolored variety (so mixed DNA: this individuum growth as red and it was sold as red). In the second case, also with cross-pollination you will not predict the colour.